# Add flags and country names to choropleth

Tags: r, choroplethr

I want to add country flags as well as country names to a choropleth on which I have already added some bars.

Some standard choropleth with bars:

```
library(cartography)

# Some standard data on Europe
data(nuts2006)

# the choropleth
choroLayer(spdf = nuts0.spdf, df = nuts0.df, var = "pop2008" , legend.pos = "n") 

# Adding Bars onto the map
propSymbolsLayer(spdf = nuts0.spdf, df = nuts0.df, 
                 var = "pop2008", symbols = "bar", col = "#920000", 
                 legend.pos = "right", legend.title.txt = "Total\npopulation (2008)", 
                 legend.style = "c")
```

If it could be close to [this](https://www.freepik.com/free-vector/map-of-europe-with-flags_1107539.htm), it would be great. But obviously, I still want it to have it as a choropleth and country names ;)

Comment: anybody got an idea? Of course I wanted to write add flags in the title